# Why can I use bounded wildcards for parameter and not for return type in a method?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

I couldn't find a better description of my question's topic, so I will try to better explain my problem. I noticed that if I use *bounded wildcards* I can use its "bound" as an **argument**, but not as a **return value**. This might sound confusing, so I will paste my code straight away.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<?> wildcardList = new ArrayList<> ();
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<> ();
    takeList (wildcardList); //compiles
    takeList (stringList); //compiles
    /////////////////////////////////////
    List<?> wildcard = returnList (); //compiles
    List<String> strings = returnList (); //doesn't compile

}

static void takeList(List<? extends Object> list){
    //some code
}

static List<? extends Object> returnList(){
    return new ArrayList<> ();
}
```

I want to know why the last line of code doesn't compile. What is the problem in that case when I explicitly said that *return type* for `returnList()` is **<? extends Object>**. And clearly String *IS-A* Object. Could someone help me clear this up?

Comment: You totally can, it's just not returning the type you expect.

Comment: I got it, my target question is why that particular line of code doesn't compile when I use "bound". In meaning that String is inside <? extends Object> bound.

Comment: Because the return type is `? extends Object`, not `String`.  Many things extend `Object`, like `Number` or `JButton`.  A list of `? extends Object` might be a list of those as well.

Comment: But String extends Object and I am not doing any add() operations which might be risky. I am sorry, I still don't understand it.

Comment: If the list type is `List<Number>`, how is that a list of String?  Generics are invariant, inheritance is covariant.  The two are different.  There's not much to say except that the language does not allow you to do what you are attempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us focus on two lines:

```
// f() returns a List<? extends Object>
List<?>      a = f(); // ok: can never do unexpected things
List<String> b = f(); // error: not 100% safe
```

For case `a`, there is no error, as a `List<? extends Object>` is exactly a `List<?>`.

For case `b`, the question for the Java compiler* is whether any sort of unexpected error (class cast) could be generated if it allowed the assignment to go through. Let us look at some examples:

- f() actually returns a List (`List<String>` is-a `List<? extends Object>`) -- no problem
- f() actually returns a List (`List<Integer>` is-a `List<? extends Object>`) -- can lead to problems, as now `b` is considered to be a `List<String>`, but `b.add("foo")` would fail.

The compiler is rightfully worried that you *may* use it improperly. Yes, it could have allowed you to go forward by checking that, indeed, you were not calling `b.add()` -- but that would complicate the compiler for very little benefit. There are many other places where compilation errors could be avoided by verifying that nothing bad will actually happen, but having simple rules ("nothing risky unless explicitly casted away") makes the rules easier to follow, and defaulting to "only allow safe things" is very much part of the Java language.

To compare:

```
// f() returns a float
float a = f(); // ok
int   b = f(); // error: not 100% safe, unwanted rounding may result!
```

(*) - I use "compiler" in a broad sense, to refer both  to the language and the compiler.

Comment: What is killing me is that if I had `<T extends Object>` instead of `<? extends Object>`, it would work. I am talking about return value as well. Could you know the difference?

Comment: While if I had used both wildcard and type variable in `parameters`, it would work in both cases. Of course add() method wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you show an example of working code with f() returning `<T extends Object>` and T different from `String` where `List<String> b = f();` compiles?

Comment: Of course. I got it all here: https://pastebin.pl/view/0a4f0483

Comment: Your pastebin example touches a different question - I suggest you ask a new question comparing the `returns List<? extends Object>` and `returns List<T>, with <T extends Object>` cases. The short version is that you cannot place a `return new ArrayList<String>()` in the second case.